# How can I reproduce TukeyHSD's difference of means?

Tags: r, anova, mean, group-differences, tukey-hsd-test

My data set comes from a series of five three-way full-factorial experiments, several of which are unbalanced. The three experimentally manipulated factors have two levels each. I am using R to analyze the data.

The ANOVA (Type 3 SS) showed several significant three-way interactions, including one which did not involve the experiment, but only the experimentally manipulated factors:

```
> # Phosphorus:Nitrogen:CO2:Experiment not significant so is dropped from the model:
> fit_a <- update(fit, .~.-Phosphorus:Nitrogen:CO2:Experiment, data=ss)
> drop1(fit_a,test="F")
Single term deletions

Model:
get(resp) ~ Phosphorus + Nitrogen + CO2 + Experiment + Phosphorus:Nitrogen + 
Phosphorus:CO2 + Nitrogen:CO2 + Phosphorus:Experiment + Nitrogen:Experiment + 
CO2:Experiment + Phosphorus:Nitrogen:CO2 + Phosphorus:Nitrogen:Experiment + 
Phosphorus:CO2:Experiment + Nitrogen:CO2:Experiment
                           Df Sum of Sq     RSS     AIC F value   Pr(>F)    
<none>                                       88.380  53.647                      
Phosphorus:Nitrogen:CO2         1     5.693  94.073  57.890  4.3157  0.041598 *  
Phosphorus:Nitrogen:Experiment  3    69.533 157.913 105.687 17.5708  1.604e-08 ***
Phosphorus:CO2:Experiment       3     6.716  95.096  54.972  1.6972  0.175975    
Nitrogen:CO2:Experiment         3    16.713 105.093  64.967  4.2233  0.008527 ** 
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1
```

Next, I ran a TukeyHSD test to examine the interaction between the experimental variables (Nitrogen, Phosphorus and CO2) and one particular result stood out:

```
>TukeyHSD(fit_a, ordered=TRUE)$"Phosphorus:Nitrogen:CO2"
                               diff        lwr      upr        p adj
[...]
Yes:Yes:Yes-Yes:Yes:No 2.300326e+00  0.9421552 3.658496 3.715101e-05
```

However, when I tried to reproduce the difference of means directly from my data set, the difference was smaller than that computed by TukeyHSD:

```
> mYYY = mean(ss[ss$Phosphorus=="Yes" & ss$Nitrogen=="Yes" & ss$CO2=="Yes", resp])
> mYYN = mean(ss[ss$Phosphorus=="Yes" & ss$Nitrogen=="Yes" & ss$CO2=="No", resp])
> mYYY - mYYN
[1] 1.566164
```

I've been trying to figure out how this can be for a while now and to no avail. Am I missing something? How can the difference computed by TukeyHSD reach 2.30 while it is only 1.57 if I calculate it myself?

**Edit**: Reproducible example here: https://gist.github.com/anonymous/7d76752a5799ae8276aeb61019bbb95e

**Edit2:** SessionInfo():

```
> sessionInfo() 
R version 3.2.3 (2015-12-10)
Platform: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu (64-bit)
Running under: Ubuntu 16.04.1 LTS

locale:
 [1] LC_CTYPE=en_CA.UTF-8       LC_NUMERIC=C               LC_TIME=en_CA.UTF-8        LC_COLLATE=en_CA.UTF-8    
 [5] LC_MONETARY=en_CA.UTF-8    LC_MESSAGES=en_CA.UTF-8    LC_PAPER=en_CA.UTF-8       LC_NAME=C                 
 [9] LC_ADDRESS=C               LC_TELEPHONE=C             LC_MEASUREMENT=en_CA.UTF-8 LC_IDENTIFICATION=C       

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] tools_3.2.3
```

Comment: Might have something to do with your unbalanced dataset. In `?TukeyHSD`in the **Details** sections it says "_This function incorporates an adjustment for sample size that produces sensible intervals for mildly unbalanced designs._" But I am not 100% though. But you should be able to check this easily using your data.

Comment: Maybe. However, from what I read in the wikipedia article, only the confidence intervals are affected by this correction. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tukey%27s_range_test#Confidence_limits

Comment: In order for people to answer your particular question you would have to provide a [reproducible example](http://adv-r.had.co.nz/Reproducibility.html). Otherwise it may turn into a guessing game. You could also look at the source code: `stats:::TukeyHSD.aov`.

Comment: I've re-run it using `fit <- aov( mean ~ Phosphorus*Nitrogen*CO2, data=data )` and removed the whole `drop` bit. When I do this the numbers match up (well, the last few decimals are different, but my assumption that there is just a numerical precision issue). So, hopefully this is a clue that can help.

Comment: Yes @Tim is right. I was also looking into this and it appears that you have some problems with "singularities" (see `summary.lm(fit)`, i.e. the first model fit in the link you provided). Using `alias(fit)` you can figure out where. It appears that "Experiment E6" is the problem. Anyway, you can either rerun without `Experiment`, or fix the problem and see if it influences/changes your model simplification process.

Comment: Also by looking at `str(data)` there is a third factor level `Lake` for the factors `Phosphorus`, `Nitrogen`, and `CO2`. The factor `Experiment` also has two "empty" factor levels, i.e. `E1` and `W1`. Not sure if this will also influence the results...

Comment: That is indeed interesting that if Experiment is not included in the model, the differences match, giving expected results. This must mean that TukeyHSD somehow gives more weight to some experiments?
Also, I am aware of the singularity issue, however it doesn't affect the results, nor do the residual factor levels. Tested by adding these lines: `data<-data[data$Experiment!="E6",]` 
`data$Experiment<-factor(data$Experiment)`
`data$Phosphorus<-factor(data$Phosphorus)`
`data$Nitrogen<-factor(data$Nitrogen)`
`data$CO2<-factor(data$CO2)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you look at the source code for TukeyHSD, you'll see that the means are calculated with model.tables(). The discussion [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/45878/r-model-tables-incorrect-means-possible-bug) seems to indicate that model.tables is not designed to work with unbalanced designs. My guess is that the function takes the mean for your 3-way interaction for each experiment and then averages those means to give you a mean across experiments. For an unbalanced design, that (marginal) mean of means is different than the mean for each combination of factors that form the interaction disregarding the experiment factor.

Comment: Hi Guillaume, thanks for your answer! I tried to first calculating the means for each experiment, and then average those means. Code:  https://gist.github.com/anonymous/082dd7a8d06ba0dcc3d75b7e03dfda81

Now, the difference between the means is greater than what was calculated by TukeyHSD! I really wish there was some documentation on how model.tables() calculates the means, as going through the source code is quite a pain...

Comment: Another thing I discovered: changing the order of the factors in the formula changes the computed mean... an undesirable property.

Comment: This simply means that model.tables() calculates marginal means in sequence, depending on the order of the factors. This makes the interpretation difficult for unbalanced designs.

Comment: Yes that makes sense. It's strange, however, that ?TukeyHSD claims to be capable of handling "mildly unbalanced designs".